# integrate the square of a derivative

Tags: integration

Suppose I have a function $\phi (t)$ and its time derivative $\dot{\phi}$. How would perform $\int \dot{\phi}^2dt$? I've tried using substitution and by parts but both seem to make the integral more complicated.

Comment: Based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817386/integral-of-derivative-squared), unless your $\phi$ is some kind of special function or can be specified further, I doubt you'll find any satisfying answer.